# Using angular ui-bootstrap and typeahead selection

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project where I am trying to use Typeahead (ui.bootstrap.typeahead) from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I have a select loading data options from a remote server(data1.json).

When the user type into select, I´d like to show on dropdown something with the format "Acrelandia - AC"(the format is cityname+' - ' +id), and the ng-model needs contain the next data:{city:'Acrelandia',state:'AC'}

Of course, The seleted text needs to be something as: "Acrelandia - AC"

I have tried the next but, I don´t know how format the result from promise to my requirements. It shows all cities in wrong format.

js:
data1:json:

```
{
  "state": [
    {
      "id": "AC",
      "name": "Acre",
      "city": [
        "Acrelandia",
        "Assis Brasil",
        "Brasileia",
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "AL",
      "name": "Alagoas",
      "city": [
        "Agua Branca",
        "Anadia",
        "Vicosa"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

js:

```
app.controller('infoController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
      $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
        return $http.get('/data1.json', {
          params: {
            address: val,
            sensor: false
          }
        }).then(function(response){
          return response.data.estados.map(function(item){
            return item.cidades.toString();
          });
        });
      };
```

Markup:

```
<div class="input-group ">
    <input type="text" ng-model="customerCity" placeholder="Type something" uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
     <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    <div ng-show="noResults">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results found
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, i dont know the answer to you question, but i did somting similar with other component   (http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) that provides similar functionality.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it.